# Appmobi just keeps at random not working

Tags: java

I've done nothing to my system settings, I havent installed anything new. nothing.. Yet at random and with no reason it seems. When I go to launch AppMobi I run into problems with JAVA not running on my system.

I have a Macbook Pro running on OS X 10.8, with JAVA 6.x running. AppMobi has been running for me without fail for a couple months now. (When OS X 10.8 first launched I had no means of launching AppMobi, before finding a way to roll the JAVA version back. Since Google has yet to release a 64 bit client for Mac and Java 7 doesn't support 32 bit browsers. I am stuck. I wish there was something just as good as AppMobi and just as free, or cheap enough to just buy cause this is ridiculous. Anyway

Anyone know what might be the issue and what might be a potential fix. AppMobi was launching and running for me earlier this morning without fail. But I put my laptop to sleep like I normally do before heading out. Went to work, came back woke it up, went to launch AppMobi again, and nothing. Just a big Grey Button that says "Download 10mb" which I downloaded, but
when I go to launch it all I get is I need to install a JAVA Runtime Environment. Which I have?

So Ideas? Sorry for the long winded body of text but I figured some dialog to the situation may be helpful to assess my issue as I havent the slightest idea otherwise whats going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with a new build of the XDK late last week.  It should be fixed at this point, though.   You can get the update by right clicking on the Impact XDK icon in Chrome, select Manage Extensions, then Update Extensions Now. That should correct the issue for you.

Comment: Something new I noticed, not sure if it was expected or not, is when I launched the XDK from the browser rather than there being "plugin not found" or "Initializing" there was a large gray button that said "download 10mb" of which I did download, but for whatever reason it wasn't working with JAVA 6.x for me. I ended up as a last ditch effort reinstalling JAVA 7, and then trying to run that download independently and it launched in the browser just fine, I do thank you though for seeking this out, and maybe what was fixed also aided in actually having it start as well.